# I've inherited a PHP project that has a very consistent file naming pattern that I don't understand

Tags: php, coding-style

Most of the files in the project are essentially pairs of files named:

1. xxxx
2. xxxx.php

inside the xxxx file is a single php statement requiring the same file name but w/ the php extension, e.g.

`<?php require('xxxx.php'); ?>`

What is the rational / programming practice / style / ... for doing this?
It's very consistent so I have to believe it is done for a rational reason.

Comment: Not the best way but maybe they didn't want the .php extension in the URL.

Comment: There's always a method to one's madness. If you were to show us a sample of both, we'd be able to shed some light on the subject ;-)

Comment: From the information given, I'm leaning towards the same reasoning that AbraCadaver said. It's maybe an attempt to do clean URLs, though an odd way of doing it.

Comment: The URL not having the extension is almost certainly the reason.

Comment: I'd have a look inside the `.htaccess` file and see if that has a whole bunch of redirects/rewrites. It stands to be a mess in there. If this is to act as a form of mod rewrite, it's just twice as many files for nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of this scheme is to achieve urls that don't end in `.php`. Like this:

```
http://www.example.com/mypage
```

instead of

```
http://www.example.com/mypage.php
```

Another way of achieving the same net effect would be to create folders for each path instead of files and have each folder contain one file called `index.php` (or whatever the default name you've configured is). Yet another way would be to use a rewrite rule configured at the web server level.

Comment: Couldn't they just achieve the same result with a mod rewrite? Edit: Ah, you've made a mention of it in an edit.